# DotNetOpen​Auth in IIS7; request not available

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, dotnetopenauth

Recently the company I work for has begun implementing OAuth in one of
their web services. However, yesterday I came across a rather unusual
problem.

When debugging the application on a remote computer, I receive the
following error: "System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available
in this context". Now, when I first encountered this problem I found
out that this usually has to do with the fact that I can't use the
HttpContext object in the Application_Start method of Global.cs, so I
removed all references to that object from the method (as described
here;
http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/11/10/Integrated-mode-Request-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-Application_5F00_Start.aspx)

However, the problem persists when running the code on the remote
computer (which is where IIS7 configuration Manager is installed).
What's more, the stack trace refers to a path named "C:\rws\lib
\dnoatst.net4\Samples\ZuydOAuthServiceProvider\Code\Global.cs", which
makes no sense to me because the actual files are located on the D:\
disk. I cannot find a reference to that path anywhere in the source
code.

Does anyone have any experience with this particular issue? Any help
would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, it seems that there is a solution to this issue, albeit not a perfect one. Setting the Application Pool's managed pipeline mode to "Classic" seems to do the trick, however, I am somewhat worried that this will cause problems at a later stage.

If anyone knows how to solve the problem described in my initial post without using Classic managed pipeline mode, I would appreciate you sharing your thoughts.

Comment: It seems that manually deleting the OAuthServiceProvider.dll and OAuthServiceProvider.pdb files (on the IIS server) and re-adding them from your local folder also helps.